# Multidimensional array pointer

Tags: c, linux

I want to save my cpu information in an array but the only thing I was able to do is to show the tmp variable. Can someone help me with this multidimensional array pointer "cpu[][][]"?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");
    char tmp[256]={0x0};
    char cpu[4][4][256]={0};// I have 4 processors.
    int i=0, j=0;
    while(file!=NULL && fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), file)!=NULL && i<4 && j<4)
    {
        if (strstr(tmp, "model name") && j==0){ 
            strcpy(cpu[i][j],tmp);
            j++;
        }
        if (strstr(tmp, "cpu MHz") && j==1){    
            strcpy(cpu[i][j],tmp);
            j++;
        }        
        if (strstr(tmp, "cache") && j==2){  
            strcpy(cpu[i][j],tmp);
            j++;
        }        
        if (strstr(tmp, "address") && j==3){ 
            strcpy(cpu[i][j],tmp);
            i++;
            j=0;
        }
    }
    if(file!=NULL) fclose(file);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            printf("Test %s\n",cpu[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change to `char cpu[4][4][256]={0};`.. `strcpy(cpu[i][j],tmp);` .. `printf("Test %s\n",cpu[0][0]);`

Comment: Test `file==NULL` before entering the `while()` loop and report on that separately.

Comment: Should you reset `j` when you increment `i`?

Comment: I edited my code to correct that but still not working

Comment: @WeatherVane The tmp variable stores the correct line and I can print it, that means file is not null but I think the problem is with this cpu[][][]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you are printing, you've incremented `j` (or set `j` to 0 and incremented `i`), so using the raw indexes in the `printf()` statement won't work.  You probably need to keep `old_i` and `old_j` around so you can use them to print the correct element of the `cpu` array, like this:

```
while (file != NULL && fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), file) != NULL && i < 4 && j < 4)
{
    int old_i = i;
    int old_j = j;
    if (strstr(tmp, "model name")){ 
        strcpy(cpu[i][j] ,tmp);
        j++;
    }
    if (strstr(tmp, "cpu MHz")){    
        strcpy(cpu[i][j], tmp);
        j++;
    }        
    if (strstr(tmp, "cache")){  
        strcpy(cpu[i][j], tmp);
        j++;
    }        
    if (strstr(tmp, "address")){ // Fix typo
        strcpy(cpu[i][j], tmp);
        i++;
        j=0;
    }
    printf("----- cpu[%d][%d] = %s\n", old_i, old_j, cpu[old_i][old_j]);
    printf("----- tmp: %s\ni = %d; j = %d\n", tmp, i, j);
}
```